# how to add Filter where Field _LINETYPE contains "1-exp"

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to coding, I need little bit of advice

I have a database in eOne Smartconnect used for GP dynamics integration

In this database I have 2 different column one is called:

1. ***_LINETYPE*** -> which contains 3 different type of data which are ("1-exp" , "2-crd" , "3-tax")
2. ***_PURCHASEAMOUNT*** which is amount for each of those type of data

Sometimes in my upload I may have 20 lines of data which are mix of those 3 different type of data so I want to create and additional column to separate the amount by type of data and filter by LINETYPE.

For example one of the new columns to say _PURCHASEAMOUNT where _LINETYPE = "1-exp" and exclude the _LINETYPE for the other two

vPurchasesAmount is the name of the new field.

here is an Example of another calculated field that works:

```
 dim vTaxDetail
 if _F9 = "T1" then
 vTaxDetail = "PS"
 else
 vTaxDetail = "PZ"
 end if
 return vTaxDetail
```

_F9 is name of another field

another example of eOne Smartconnect codes:

```
dim vCashChequebook

if fn.left(_F2, 5) = "PCASH"then
return "MISC PETTY CASH"
else
return string.empty
end if
```

_F2 is name of another field

so far I have tried this but it still picks up the PURCHASEAMOUNT for all 3

```
dim vPurchasesAmount

if _LINETYPE= "1-exp" then vPurchasesAmount = _PURCHASEAMOUNT
 else vPurchasesAmount = "0" end if

return vPurchasesAmount
```

Comment: Little hard to know, guessing you're iterating over some list or collection maybe.  Really this sounds like a straight debugging issue, likely that _LINETYPE is not what you're expecting, how is the value for that being set?  Perhaps, put a breakpoint on the  if condition line and inspect the value is correct

Comment: There are only 3 different values in _LINETYPE field, which I want to filter based on those 3 different values in 3 new different fields, each field for each value in _LINETYPE Field

Comment: Yeah, sorry you didn't really answer the questions.  1) how is the value of _LINETYPE set 2)  At the point where you're evaluating it, what is the "ACTUAL" value and is that what you expect?